# interface with internal property

Tags: c#, interface, properties, internal

I am creating an interface. Lets say the following

```
internal interface MyInterface
{
    string Prop { get; }
}
```

This is an internal interface. I indent to use this within the project and do not want to expose `Prop` publicly. However when I try to implement this interface into a class, I am forced to make the `Prop` property public. I do not understand why I need to make this property public when the interface itself is internal and can only be used internally.

Comment: Put the interface inside the class so it is internal.  Putting in outside the class forces you to make it public.

Comment: @jdweng it doesn't work. No matter where I place it, it is still static

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because an interface itself is only a contract of public-facing functionality for an object.  Anything non-public doesn't really belong there, but could instead go on the implementing type.

It's essentially a non-issue, however.  If the *type* is `internal`, then any properties on the type aren't visible outside of that scope.  Because how could they be?  The type itself isn't known outside of that scope.  (Any code which doesn't know what `MyInterface` is certainly isn't going to know what `MyInterface.Prop` is.)

The properties are `public` in the sense that consuming code can see them.  But this only matters to code which can consume that type in the first place, which is only `internal` to that assembly.

Comment: I get that `MyInterface.Prop` will not be visible outside it's scope and that's what I need. But that being considered, why does the property have to be public when it can't be use outside it's scope anyways?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane: Because interfaces are definitions of public-facing functionality.  Note that the interface *itself* doesn't define the visibility of things.  Because everything is public.  What would happen if one implementing type marked the property as `public` and another as `protected`?  The second one wouldn't actually be implementing the interface.  The compiler can't allow that.

Comment: There's also the situation where you have internal IMyInterfaceA, internal IMyInterfaceB and you can't use IMyInterfaceB as an argument in IMyInterfaceB because the member where you want to use it must be public and the type of the argument is less visible than the member